# target="_blank" in h:commandlink not opening page in new tab of browser

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

My h:commandLink is opening/previewing the pdf document on same page/window when h:commandlink used  with target="_blank". I want it to be opened in new tab of the browser

where can be the error?

Preview.xhtml code:

```
<h:commandLink  id="DocUpoadPreview" action="#{documentController.previewUploadedFile}" value="Preview" target="_blank" >

             </h:commandLink>
```

In previewuploadedFile() action encription/decryption and some other process with pdf is required that is why necessary to use and that is why not using h:outputlink here. After the action process i want to redirect to another page(previewUploadedDoc.xhtml) which uses primefaces p:media tag to preview the document.

```
public String previewUploadedFile() throws Exception {


  //decryption process and adding water mark here//
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
        .redirect("previewUploadedDoc.xhtml");}
```

Comment: did you try "_new" instead of "_blank"?

Comment: "_new" is working for me. (Using JSF 2 and Firefox)

Comment: I had the same problem. I added ajax="false" and it worked for me.

Comment: @Mr.PortStJoe: Ajax="false" is not supported on plain jsf commandLink

Answer (score 3):

Try it:

```
<h:commandLink  id="DocUpoadPreview" action="#{documentController.previewUploadedFile}" value="Preview" target="_new" />
```

Answer (score -1):

target="_new" is not valid value of target. It defines _new as a name of new page.

This is the valids values:  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp